# Angle between surface normal and arc normal of Frenet Serret frame

Tags: differential-geometry

Is the the angle $\varphi$ indicating deviation of geodesy ( in Meusnier's thm) always $ \pi/2 $ for an asymptotic line with $ k_n =0 $ ? (I could not find such a statement in textbooks I referred to).

$$ \tan \varphi = \frac{k_g}{k_n}  $$

EDIT 1:

Meusnier's thm:

$$ \cos\varphi = \frac{k_n}{k} = \frac{k_n}{\sqrt{k_n^2 + k_g^2} }.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a regular surface and let $c \colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\subset \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S$ be a regular curve parametrized by arc length. Let $p:=c(0)$, then we consider the vector $$c''(0).$$ Clearly $c''(0)$ its not necessarily in the tangent space $T_pS$. Therefore, we consider the following decomposition: $$c''(0)=[c''(0)]^T+[c''(0)]^N.$$ where $[c''(0)]^T$ is the tangential component and $[c''(0)]^N$ the normal component of $c''(0)$ respectively. Now $$[c''(0)]^N=\underbrace{\langle c''(0),N(p)\rangle}_{k_N(c(0),c'(0)):=} N(p),\ \ \ (\dagger) $$ where $N$ is the unit normal of $S$ and $k_N(c(0),c'(0))$ in the normal curvature of $S$ at $c(0)$ (in the direction $c'(0)$). By using the Frenet equations you obtain immediately Meusniers theorem. Also the tangential component is related in the same sense  with what we call *''geodesic curvature''*. Thus the well known relation $$k^2=k_g^2+k_N^2$$ is just the Pythagorean theorem of $(\dagger)$. Now, as you can see if $[c''(s)]^N$ vanishes  ($\Leftrightarrow k_N(c(s),c'(s))=0\Leftrightarrow c''(s)\in T_{c(s)}S$ ) then you have the asymptotic curves. Also, if $[c''(s)]^T$ vanishes  ($\Leftrightarrow k_g(c(s))=0\Leftrightarrow c''(s)\in \mathrm{span}\{(N\circ c)(s)\}$ ) then you have the geodesic curves. Therefore, the geodesic curves of a regular surface are just curves of zero acceleration* which of course locally minimize length.

*Acceleration is of course with respect to the surface (meaning the Levi-Civita connection of $S$.)

Hope i helped!

Comment: So if tangential and osculating planes are one and same, what happens to $ \varphi?$ Can it be determined?

Comment: Of course! If tangential and osculating plane coincide along a curve then the curve is an asympototic curve and $\phi=\angle(N,n)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.